# SDL12 Error when compiling gstreamer (python kivy) app

Tags: python, windows, compilation, kivy

I am trying to compile an app with Pyinstaller that just plays a video following the kivy's official documentation. But I have an error `*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins + gstreamer.dep_bins)]`

`NameError: name 'sdl2' is not defined`

What could be I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import the module `sdl2`?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your spec file, you need:

```
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer
```